# EXCEL: Find cells via last number

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

So I need a way to mark the cells where the sequence ends in 4, 5, or 6.

```
Data
35632
35215
35115
etc.
```

I don't have an idea of where to start so any help is much appreciated. I know that I can't use the text filters on numbers even if the cell is formatted as text.

Comment: What do you mean "mark the cells"?

Comment: Either true or false in the adjacent column or highlighting the cell itself.

Comment: So something like an Excel formula of `=OR(MOD(A1,10)=4,MOD(A1,10)=5,MOD(A1,10)=6)`?  Does it need to be VBA?  Can you just use conditional formatting?

Comment: Formulas work fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use one of the following Excel formulas

```
=OR(MOD(A1,10)=4,MOD(A1,10)=5,MOD(A1,10)=6)
```

or

```
=OR(RIGHT(A1)="4",RIGHT(A1)="5",RIGHT(A1)="6")
```

or (thanks to Scott Craner)

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(--RIGHT(A1),{4,5,6},0))
```

or

```
=ISNUMBER(MATCH(MOD(A1,10),{4,5,6},0))
```

or

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(MOD(A1,10),"456"))
```

or

```
=ISNUMBER(FIND(RIGHT(A1),"456"))
```

or

```
=SUM(IF(MOD(A1,10)={4,5,6},1))              (returns 1 if true, or 0 if false)
```

OR

```
=OR(MOD(A1,10)={4,5,6})
```

Or

```
=MOD(MOD(A1,10),7)>3
```

Or

```
=ABS(RIGHT(A1)-5)<2
```

Comment: the `,1` in the right is not needed.  It defaults to `1`.  so the shortest answer is `=ISNUMBER(FIND(RIGHT(A1),"456"))`  I do not think we can get shorter than that.

Comment: @ScottCraner I didn't realise that!  (P.S.  This did seem like it was getting into a Code Golf question :D)

Comment: @ScottCraner Only after you mentioned the redundant `,1`, so we will have to share the honours!  (Until someone thinks of something we haven't !! :D)

Comment: @ScottCraner Two bytes less!

Comment: And, with that, I am going to stop playing :D

Comment: How about this? `=MOD(MOD(A1,10),7)>3`

Comment: @CallumDA Edit it into the answer. (I made it a community wiki as soon as Scott made his first suggestion, so you are free to edit it as much as you like.)  And congratulations, that cuts 3 bytes off Scott's last suggestion :D

Comment: Chuffed :D. Nice idea making it community wiki -- now added my solution

Comment: @CallumDA Not sure whether Code Golf and Stack Overflow should overlap like this, but it's fun anyway. :D

Comment: @CallumDA - LOL - at the rate you are going, we'll end up getting this down to just `=` !

Comment: @YowE3K, haha I had a bit of time on my hands.. I don't think I can do any better than that for now, but very interested to see any future improvements!